# Rails 6 routes - how to add custom "new" route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'd like to add a custom rails route - the default way is something like this:

`/cars/new`

I'd like to keep this route available and would also want to add a route like this:

`/cars/new/:manufacturer_slug`

and then just in the view/controller to check what is in params and based on that show different content.

How do I do that?

I tried to add it through resources, like

```
resources :end do
  get 'new/:manufacturer_slug',                   to: 'cars#new'
end
```

or

```
resources :end do
  member do
    get 'new/:manufacturer_slug',                   to: 'cars#new'
  end
end
```

but neither version works - in both cases I just get an error about a wrong URL.

Answer (score 1):

A more RESTful, conventional and altogether better solution would be to [declare a nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

```
resources :manufacturers, only: [] do
  resources :cars, 
    only: [:new, :create], 
    module: :manufacturers
end
```

This would declare the route `/manufacturers/:manufacturer_id/cars/new`. Not that just because the parameter is called `manufacturer_id` doesn't mean you can't use a slug instead of the primary key. Identifiers are whatever you want them to be.

This route is much less wonky as the path itself describes the relation between the two resources and its very clear that you are creating a resource that belongs to another.

```
module Manufactorers
  class CarsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_manufacturer

    # GET /manufacturers/acme/cars/new
    def new
      @car = @manufacturer.cars.new
    end

    # POST /manufacturers/acme/cars
    def create
      @car = @manufacturer.cars.new(car_params)
      if @car.save
        redirect_to @car
      else
        render :new
      end
    end

    private

    def set_manufacturer
      # adapt this to your own slugging solution
      @manufacturer = Manufacturer.find_by_slug_or_id(params[:id])
    end

    def car_params
      params.require(:car)
            .permit(:foo, :bar, :baz)
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

```
<%= form_with model: [@manufacturer, @car] do |form| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
resources :cars do
  collection do
    get 'new/:manufacturer_slug', to: 'cars#new'
  end
end
```

or

```rb
get 'cars/new/:manufacturer_slug', to: 'cars#new'
```

check the result with `rails routes`.

or you can just add the param at the end of url:
`/cars/new?manufacturer_slug=anything`